# Redirect with HTTP_HOST redirects to sub subdomain

Tags: htaccess, redirects, subdomain

**The settings**

I have the following *.htaccess* rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^de\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great to redirect any subdomain that is not valid (`www` or `de`) to the `www` subdomain.

I have seen solution, but they only depend on single domain sites.

I have multiple domains:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.net
http://de.example.com
```

which all serve their own brand of site.

Now I have the *.htaccess* rule that is mentioned above and it works beautifully if someone types in `http://example.com` it redirects to `http://www.example.com`.

**The problem**

If someone types in `http://test.example.com`, it redirects to `http://www.test.example.com` and if someone types in `http://test.example.net`, it redirects to `http://www.test.example.net`.

**The question**

How can I make it so that it redirects `http://test.example.com` to `http://www.example.com`? And `http://test.example.net` to `http://www.example.net`.

I need an domain insensitve solution because more domains will be added in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect using the sub-domain as a parameter:

> `# HTTP 301 Redirect test.*.net -> www.*.net`
>   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.([^.]+).net$ [NC]`
>   `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1.net/$1 [R=301,L)`
>   
>   `# HTTP 301 Redirect test.*.com -> www.*.com`
>   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.([^.]+).com$ [NC]`
>   `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,L)`

If you also want to redirect when there's no subdomain (e.g. `http://example.com`) to the main website using the `www.` subdomain (`http://www.example.com`):

> `# HTTP 301 Redirect *.net -> www.*.net`
>   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).net$ [NC]`
>   `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1.net/$1 [R=301,L)`
>   
>   `# HTTP 301 Redirect *.net -> www.*.net`
>   `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+).com$ [NC]`
>   `RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%1.com/$1 [R=301,L)`

If you're trying to achieve a lot with your `.htaccess` files you may find it helps to test your conditions and how they affect URL rewriting on the [htaccess Made-With-Love](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) website.

In case this is where you struggled, it is always worth remembering that in `.htaccess`, parameters prefixed with percent symbols (e.g. `%1`) reference values from the last matched `RewriteCond` expression, normally values that have been marked as being of interest by being surrounded in brackets `()`, and parameters prefixed with dollar symbols (e.g. `$1`) reference values in the `RewriteRule` expression, normally values that are automatically assigned by Apache and relating to the URL.